# SVG Text Path in Power BI Visuals - Failing in Firefox/Edge - Can It Work?

Tags: svg, powerbi

After some cross-browser testing i'm finding that SVG text paths seem to break in Power BI custom visuals, at least in recent versions of Firefox or Edge. They work fine in recent and not so recent Chrome, as well as in IE11.

The code in the JSFiddle below works correctly in Firefox, displaying "hello" along the path and proving the browser handles the functionality, however close to equivalent code which can be compiled directly in Power BI DevTools shows the text sat at 0,0, disconnected from the path. In Chrome though, it appears as it does in the JSFiddle.

[JSFiddle to demonstrate issue](https://jsfiddle.net/tg5nh2ox/1/)

IVisual demo code:

```
module powerbi.visuals {

export class newVisual implements IVisual {
    public static capabilities: VisualCapabilities = {
        dataRoles: [
            {
                name: "Category",
                kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Grouping
            },
            {
                name: "Y",
                kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure
            }
        ],
        dataViewMappings: [{
            categorical: {
                categories: {
                    for: { in: "Category" }
                }
            }
        }]
    };

    private root: D3.Selection;
    private gCont: D3.Selection;

    public init(options: VisualInitOptions): void {

        options.viewport.width=500;
        options.viewport.height=500;

        this.root = d3.select(options.element.get(0))
            .append('svg')
            .attr("width", options.viewport.width)
            .attr("height", options.viewport.height);

        this.gCont = this.root
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

        var line = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .y(function(d) {
            return d.y;
          }).interpolate("linear");

        this.gCont
          .append("path")
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .attr("id", "pathid")
          .attr("d", function() {
            return line([{"x": 100, "y": 100}, {"x": 200, "y": 150}]);
          });

        this.gCont
          .append("text")
          .append("textPath")
          .text("hello")
          .attr("xlink:href", "#pathid");
}

    public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {}
    public destroy() {}
}
```

}

Have I forgotten to set something that's causing this problem, or is this a genuine incompatibility that cannot currently be overcome?

Note - I'm aware of the bug that requires the xlink:href to be constantly re-set during a transition - that exists in my more complex code with animation, and does it's job in Chrome etc - it does not help with this issue.

Output in Firefox (cut down - the whole thing is quite large even in DevTools):

```
<div class="visualContainer visual">
<svg height="500" width="500">
<g transform="translate(50,50)">
<path d="M100,100L200,150" id="pathid" style="stroke: black;"></path>
<text><textPath xlink:href="#pathid">hello</textPath></text>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the DOM that Power BI DevTools produces in Firefox to the question.

Comment: I've added what I think you're asking for above. Notably, when used standalone in Firefox it also displays correctly. Is this what you meant for me to include?

Comment: That DOM works so there must be more to it than that. Are there any `<base>` tags in the complete DOM?

Comment: There is indeed a base tag in the <head> portion: <base href="/" />

Comment: I've also confirmed that removing that <base> node and recompiling the code in DevTools resolves the issue immediately, so you've nailed the cause. The only question now is whether there's any way to work around this. All I've found so far suggests a fully qualified URL would be required in this scenario, and I don't think there's going to be a consistent one to apply unfortunately. Even if the DevTools one seems somewhat consistent, the one in the real PowerBI web app is constantly varied, and the visual needs to work all over the place.